# Ember promise - accessing value - use the RSVP method?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am working on an Ember application..

Its using Ember.inject.service modules -- and its not resolving the promise - not providing just the string I need from it

I have a service that looks like this

```
let downloadMethod = this.get('service1')
  .fetch(id)
  .then(res => {
    console.log("res", res.agenda.method.value)
    res.agenda.method.value
 });

console.log("downloadMethod", downloadMethod);
```

when I try to access this -- the console log for downloadmethod shows a promise -- but inside the then -- res comes out as the string value I need.

how do I get the value out of the "downloadMethod" -- it shows as a promise, instead of a string result?

Do I need to wrap this around an Ember.RSVP.hash?

Comment: What was your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: it just displays a promise - as opposed to the value I need to get from the promise

Comment: no its using an ember injected service - not ajax

Comment: how do I get the value out of the "downloadMethod" -- it shows as a promise, instead of a string result

Comment: This is how asynchronous programming works. See the duplicate.

Comment: I've explained several times -- downloadMethod is console logging out as a promise instead of a string - why

Comment: Ember.RSVP.hash --- this is maybe what I need

Comment: You need to read more about asynchronous programming and Promises.

Comment: @rmlan - I do know about asynchronous programming and Promise. It would be good if you could provide actual Ember injection based service examples

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The actual solution to this was to create a return RSVP.hash in the model parent.

```
model () {
    return RSVP.hash({
      deliveryMethod: this.get('service1').fetch(this.get('service2').id).then(res => {
         return res.agenda.method.value;
      })
    });
},
```

Comment: service2 was not mentioned in the original example code. Could you clean up the question so we can understand this answer?

Comment: @Gaurav it doesn't matter - this service2 was used to get an id - so really just an id is returned at that juncture -- "this.get('service2').id" -- its used to fetch a record - so what you have is a chain. I don't really know how else to explain it - given you have the exact code - and the problem throughout -- whenever I tried to access "downloadMethod" it would return a promise -- then just a fetched string. --- its a giant 50-100 file Ember project -- and so not even Paul's answer satisfies the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

The `console.log("downloadMethod", downloadMethod)` is called before the promise finishes, so you don't have the string value yet. You just have the unresolved promise.

So you need to save the value inside the `then` function. Below is some code to show what that looks like if this was inside an Ember Component

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Component.extend({
  service1: service(),
  fetchedValue: null,

  actions: {
    someAction() {
      this.get('service1')
        .fetch(id)
        .then(res => {
          this.set('fetchedValue', res.agenda.method.value);
        });
    }
  }
})
```

This code is Ember version 2.16 and above

Comment: That's a possible way -- but I do need to obtain the fetchedvalue at the level of a call to action.

Comment: @TheOldCounty I updated my code example to fetch the data in an action.

Comment: the problem is - this is only part of a very very complicated pre-built Ember application. I'm already going to have to hijack and prevent an action to run this promise -- and I'm more of a react js dev

Comment: @Gaurav - I understand that - but the code is written in Ember. It appears several services are merged using RSVP